# Why cannot see Axel window?

Tags: lubuntu, downloads, window, axel

I have installed axel and set it to get my firefox downloads through flashgot. It works but the Axel window is not visible - so cannot know when the download starts and ends, its speed etc.

I have recently installed Lubuntu Precise. Before I was using the same but the main installation was Xubuntu and did not have this problem.

Comment: are you using any script?

Comment: It's working fine for me.

Comment: no scripts installed in firefox. after reinstalling axel, the same problem

Comment: I'll try on Lubuntu and get back to you.

Comment: added the (tested) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initiate the download the status is not shown in the terminal installed in lubuntu, but on 'xterm'. All you have to do is to install xterm:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

'xterm' comes installed with Ubuntu and Xubuntu, that's why it worked fine when you had Xubuntu with `lubuntu-desktop` installed.

Comment: i had lxterm, xfce4-term and gnome terminal installed, i didn't imagine something else was missing, but after installing xterm it is ok

Answer (score 1):

Is a window created with other console downloaders? (wget, aria2).

start any long download and run in terminal `ps -C xterm,axel ww`.Also you can try to run xterm from terminal `xterm`.
Try the following variants:

1. 'Alt+Tab' to take out the hidden window. Sometimes it helps. But I don't know if this combo works in lubuntu.
2. Write down a command line for axel manually in the flashgot options.
3. Reinstall flashgot.

Comment: no window with wget either. `ps -C xterm,axel ww` gives just `  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND`. alt-tab is real in lubuntu but axel is not there.

Comment: could not find a command line that worked, and that was not the question anyway. reinstalling flashgot did not helped

Comment: downgrading flashgot version did not help

Comment: I meant any flashgot-axel download. What does the command `xterm` give? Possibly you don't have the xterm program or it is broken.

Comment: yes, that was it. but the other answer is more up to the point so i'll make that the one. upvote and thnk you